# Partition SSD in Yosemite for Dual-Booting Ubuntu

Tags: macos, partition, unix, dual-boot, core-storage

I've just bought a new Macbook Air (running Yosemite) and I am trying to create a partition from my Macintosh HD SSD for dual-booting Ubuntu. However when I try to create a partition in Disk Utilities, I keep getting the error "This Core Storage operation is not allowed on a sparse logical volume group." I have tried restarting the system in Recovery Mode and verifying and repairing the disk, but it did not work.  What can I do to partition? (I would prefer to not format the SSD.)

[image: disk utilities screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You have to boot from another device or to Internet Recovery Mode and then use the command line to modify the CoreStorage volume.

**Preparation:**

- Backup your data.
- Detach any external drive (especially your external Time Machine backup drive).
- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.
  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot to a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an apple/akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

  Alternatively you may start from a bootable installer thumb drive (Mavericks or Yosemite) or a thumb drive containing a full system (Mavericks or Yosemite).

**Modify CoreStorage:**

- Open in the menubar Utilities/Terminal
- Enter `diskutil cs list`
- Enter `diskutil cs resizeStack LVUUID size` with LVUUID: UUID of the logical volume and size: the final size of your Macintosh HD
  Example: `diskutil cs resizeStack DC2473AF-0833-4DBD-BF8F-D5D60063554A 200g`
- Enter `exit` and quit Terminal.
- Reboot to your main volume.
- Start installing Ubuntu to the now unallocated disk space.